# How to get 503 error code instead of 504 when my API is down?

Tags: api, mule, http-status-codes

I have developed my API and registered in mule API Manager.

When my API is down and trying to hit the API from Postman tool getting below error.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally it should be 503 – Service unavailable. Any options to get error code 503 instead of 504 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you API in API manager is down, there is nothing you can do. If your backend implementation is down you could do something will policies to override the status code.

But as your API in API manager is down, there is nothing in your control.

504 is still technically valid as nginx is acting as a proxy and it cannot reach your API.

But I would not worry about it. all API client should handle 5XX status code the same. As in 'Server Error' and can possibly be retried later.

Also with API down in API manager, the 504 should take a while to get a response back. So I would probably set a decent request timeout before reaching that point.

Answer (score 1):

That really isn't in your control. The difference between 503 and 504 is that 503 means that your app-server has issues, while 504 means that the gateway you're using has issues.

For example, if I am using nginx as a gateway, and I'm redirecting to some app server. If the app server is down, then nginx will return 503.
If, however, the app server is unresponsive, or if nginx itself is failing (due to load, or other issues), the response will be 504.

In general, you shouldn't be worried about what the response is. 5xxs are treated roughly the same in most situations, and they mean server issues.